# frappe_docker connect to local mariadb instead of dockerized mariadb

Tags: docker, mariadb, erpnext, frappe

I'm trying to explore ERPNext on my Windows10 PC.

I've XAMPP running in my PC.

I've installed & running ERPNext using frappe_docker. It's working well.

Now, I'm trying to view the data in database. I think I've two options here-

- Either, Connect my database client to the mariadb running in docker.
- Or, force frappe_docker to use my local mariadb server.

Unfortunately, I could not perform any of the options, due to the lack of enough knowledge.
I googled a lot, but did not find useful solution.

Any help?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am trying to connect my db client to the docker MariaDB Server but get an access denied error.

connection details :

host: localhost
port: 3306
db: erpnext
uid: admin
pwd: admin